# Is it somewhere documented how the Windows energy profile influences .NET performance?

Tags: .net, winforms, performance

I already asked a question about bad performance when disabling winforms controls where I found that it was a problem when the energy profile was set to balanced. This week we got another case. A customer of us was complaining about bad performance in our .NET application. I remembered my experience with the winforms controls and we asked him to check it. The result: in some scenarios the application was two to six times faster just setting the profile from balanced to high performance!!!

This is very strange as this application is a business one where a client communicates with an application server using remoting. The application server connects to an Oracle server. You see: quite a lot of time should be spent just with the communication. Fist we investigated our Oracle queries, then our communication layer and at the end the energy profile was costing most of the time.

This is quite a big difference as the laptops were working connected to the power supply and not on batteries. Are there any documents explaining the influence of the energy profile with .NET applications? The customer tells us that the "other" software (he means Office) is not affected as much as the .NET application. Is this some problem with the JIT compiler?

Comment: Power management on commodity hardware is a mess.  It is the only way a system builder can distinguish himself from his competitors that use the exact same components.  The "vendor recommended power profile" in the Control Panel applet was only designed to keep users happy, not to make machines fast.  So the battery lasts longer and the cooling fan doesn't turn on.  How much less of a PC you get is unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

If you dig into the energy profile, you will see that there is only one setting, which severely can influence performance: (other settings like HDD spindown delay and WiFi power have only minor influence)

- maximum clockrate (CPU)

on some profiles (especially on battery) it is already limited to somewhat 60% out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Florian. I know how the energy profiles are working. The strange thing is that the "Balanced" profile is so slow even when you are connected and not on batteries. My question is more about it hurting specially the .NET applications. The customer tell us that the other apps are ok about their performance but the .NET app is much slower.

Comment: Have you checked the max CPU clock specifically? I could imagine, because .NET uses JIT, it has more impact on those applications.
as far as i know, nothing else (performance related) is connected to these profiles - I may stand corrected - is there any additional software installed, which could change settings depending on these profiles?

Comment: Yes, this is our assumption too. We suppose that the JIT needs more CPU or that the way the JIT works is causing these slowdowns. As we understand it, the CPU is probably transitioning too often from one speed to the other and the transition itself is costing too much performance. It looks as if the system runs a little bit, slows down, runs a little bit and so on. This is the reason I asked for any papers that  explained it (and best case tell how to disable this behaviour)